# angular encode url search string

Tags: angularjs, url-encoding

how do i encode the keyword that get sent to the server and then decode it?

I can't search for keywords containing chars like .? or / at the moment.

**The code displaying is wrong because endpoint returns a object.**

```
 self.search = function (keyword) {
            var endpoint = $location.path(baseEndpoint + "search/").search(keyword),
                deferred = $q.defer();

            $http.get(HttpRequestUrlHelper.ensureUniqueRequestUrl(endpoint), {
            }).success(function (response) {
                deferred.resolve(response);
            }).error(function (error) {
                deferred.reject(error);
            });

            return deferred.promise;
        }
```

If i use encodeURIComponent() my url is encoded but my controller isn't hit:

```
request url => /todo/search/Leka%20med%20barnen.?UniqueKey=1404655031784 angular.js:9159
GET http://localhost:49195/todo/search/Leka%20med%20barnen.?UniqueKey=1404655031784 404 (Not Found)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up making a query string instead:

```
var endpoint = baseEndpoint + "search?keyword=" + keyword,
```

Comment: I think it's more suitable anyway. It's more RESTFUL to use path variables only when they serve as coordinates for the requested resources.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the escape function: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_escape.asp

Comment: The escape() function was deprecated in JavaScript version 1.5. Use encodeURI() or encodeURIComponent() instead.

But doesen't angular have something for this?

Comment: When i use encodeURIComponent() it encodes the string but console outputs a 404. My controllers breakpoint isent hit. Updates my question.

Comment: Why would he need one if this methods do the job?

Comment: Why you get 404 is hard to answer without seeing anything from your server side configuration. 
If you try constructing the request with something like https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo, do you also get 404?